# Plotting Average curve for points in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, average

[Current]

I am importing a text file in which the first column has simulation time (0~150) the second column has the delay (0.01~0.02).

```
1.000000 0.010007
1.000000 0.010010
2.000000 0.010013
2.000000 0.010016
.
.
.
149.000000 0.010045
149.000000 0.010048
150.000000 0.010052
150.000000 0.010055
```

which gives me the plot:
[image: Instantanous Delay in Seconds]

---

[Desired]

I need to plot an average line on it like shown in the following image with red line:

[image: Average red line]

Answer (score 11):

Here is a gnuplot only solution with sample data:

```
set table "test.data"
set samples 1000
plot rand(0)+sin(x)
unset table
```

You should check the [gnuplot demo](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.4/data_feedback.html) page for a running average. I'm going to generalize this demo in terms of dynamically building the functions. This makes it much easier to change the number of points include in the average.

This is the script:

```
# number of points in moving average
n = 50

# initialize the variables
do for [i=1:n] {
    eval(sprintf("back%d=0", i))
}

# build shift function (back_n = back_n-1, ..., back1=x)
shift = "("
do for [i=n:2:-1] {
    shift = sprintf("%sback%d = back%d, ", shift, i, i-1)
} 
shift = shift."back1 = x)"
# uncomment the next line for a check
# print shift

# build sum function (back1 + ... + backn)
sum = "(back1"
do for [i=2:n] {
    sum = sprintf("%s+back%d", sum, i)
}
sum = sum.")"
# uncomment the next line for a check
# print sum

# define the functions like in the gnuplot demo
# use macro expansion for turning the strings into real functions
samples(x) = $0 > (n-1) ? n : ($0+1)
avg_n(x) = (shift_n(x), @sum/samples($0))
shift_n(x) = @shift

# the final plot command looks quite simple
set terminal pngcairo
set output "moving_average.png"
plot "test.data" using 1:2 w l notitle, \
     "test.data" using 1:(avg_n($2)) w l lc rgb "red" lw 3 title "avg\\_".n
```

This is the result:

[image: moving average]

The average lags quite a bit behind the datapoints as expected from the algorithm. Maybe 50 points are too many. Alternatively, one could think about implementing a centered moving average, but this is beyond the scope of this question.
And, I also think that you are more flexible with an external program :)

Comment: Nice work. If your x axis is just plain integers, you can recenter the average curve via `plot "test.data" using ($1-n/2):(avg_n($2))`. Note that in order for the `@` notation to work, you may need to add `set macros` at the top of the script.

Answer (score 7):

Here's some replacement code for the top answer, which makes this also work for 1000+ points and much much faster. Only works in gnuplot 5.2 and later I guess

```
# number of points in moving average
n = 5000

array A[n]

samples(x) = $0 > (n-1) ? n : int($0+1)
mod(x) = int(x) % n
avg_n(x) = (A[mod($0)+1]=x, (sum [i=1:samples($0)] A[i]) / samples($0))
```

Answer (score 6):

For gnuplot>=5.2, probably the most efficient solution is using an array like @Franky_GT's solution.
However, it uses the pseudocolumn 0 (see `help pseudocolumns`). In case you have some double empty lines in your data `$0` will be reset to `0` which might mess up your average.

This solution uses an index `t` to count up the datalines and two `N` sized arrays `Y[]` and `X[]`. The latter is for the case a *centered moving average* is desired. Datapoints don't have to be equidistant in x.

**Script:** (working for gnuplot>=5.2.0,. Sept. 2017)

```
### moving average over N points
reset session

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    set samples 5000
    y0 = 0
    plot '+' u 0:(y0=y0+rand(0)*2-1) w table
unset table

# average over N values
N = 250
array X[N]
array Y[N]

AvgX(colX) = (X[t%N+1]=column(colX),        n=(t<N ? t : N), (sum [i=1:n] X[i])/n)
AvgY(colY) = (Y[t%N+1]=column(colY), t=t+1, n=(t<N ? t : N), (sum [i=1:n] Y[i])/n)

plot $Data u 1:2 w l ti "Data", \
     t=0 '' u         1:(AvgY(2)) w l      lc rgb "red"   ti "Moving average over ".N, \
     t=0 '' u (AvgX(1)):(AvgY(2)) w l lw 2 lc rgb "green" ti "Moving average centered over ".N
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

The updated question is about a [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average).

You can do this in a limited way with gnuplot alone, according to [this demo](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.4/data_feedback.html).

But in my opinion, it would be more flexible to pre-process your data using a programming language like [python](https://www.python.org/) or [ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) and add an extra column for whatever kind of moving average you require.

*The original answer is preserved below:*

---

You can use `fit`. It seems you want to fit to a constant function. Like this:

```
f(x) = c

fit f(x) 'S1_delay_120_LT100_LU15_MU5.txt' using 1:2 every 5 via c
```

Then you can plot them both.

```
plot 'S1_delay_120_LT100_LU15_MU5.txt' using 1:2 every 5, \
f(x) with lines
```

Note that this is technique can be used with arbitrary functions, not just constant or lineair functions.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to comment on Franky_GT, but somehow stackoverflow didn't let me.

However, Franky_GT, your answer works great!

A note for people plotting .xvg files (e.g. after doing analysis of MD simulations), if you don't add the following line:

```
set datafile commentschars "#@&"
```

Franky_GT's moving average code will result in this error:

```
unknown type in imag()
```

I hope this is of use to anyone.