# Gnuplot, linespoints + histogram, one graph, two datafiles

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

Reading in the gnuplot manual has not helped me with this, and my internet searches haven't been fruitful either. I'm using `gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 0`

I'm plotting the following graph with data from a file, plus a calculated moving average added (code below)
[image: Graph with moving average]
The file used is this, `graph.dat`:

```
20180607-1200 20.4
20180611-1200 23.2
20180617-1200 22.1
```

I'd like to add a histogram at the bottom of the graph, based on another file with the same x-values, `histogram.dat`:

```
20180607-1200 18.95
20180611-1200 18.52
20180617-1200 18.76
```

and I've tried with the following code:

```
set terminal png size 640,396
set border front lw 1

# Make left y-axis ticks and numbers disappear
set ytics scale 0
set ytics textcolor rgb "white"

set y2tics
set y2range [18.5:25.7]

set output 'graph.png'

set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y%m%d-%H%M"
set xtics timedate
set xtics format "%Y-%m-%d"
set xtics rotate
set mxtics 7
# A week is 604800 seconds
set xtics "20180607-1200",604800,"20180617-1200"
set offsets graph 0.015, graph 0.015, 0, 0

# For moving average
samples(x) = $0 > 4 ? 5 : ($0+1)
avg5(x) = (shift5(x), (back1+back2+back3+back4+back5)/samples($0))
shift5(x) = (back5=back4, back4=back3, back3=back2, back2=back1, back1=x)

# Initialize the running sum
init(x) = (back1 = back2 = back3 = back4 = back5 = sum = 0)

# Plot data, running average, and histogram
plot sum = init(0), \
"graph.dat" using 1:2 axes x1y2 title "graph" with linespoints, \
'' using 1:(avg5($2)) axes x1y2 title "moving average" with linespoints, \
"histogram.dat" using 1:2 axes x1y2 title "histogram" with histogram clustered
```

but after adding the last line (beginning with `"histogram.dat"`) it returns the following error message:

```
plot sum = init(0), "graph.dat" using 1:2 axes x1y2 title "graph" with linespoints, '' using 1:(avg5($2)) axes x1y2 title "moving average" with linespoints, "histogram.dat" using 1:2 axes x1y2 title "histogram" with histogram clustered
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ^
"grapher.gp", line 35: Too many columns in using specification
```

which I don't understand.
I'm aiming for a graph with a small histogram at the bottom, like in this constructed example:
[image: Constructed example]
*Question:* What am I doing wrong? How can I do `linespoints` and `histogram` based on two different files shown in one graph? [I have since found out that one has to use `boxes` instead of `histogram` for this - see my own answer below]

*Bonus question:* Is there a better way to avoid showing the y1 axis numbers, better than my hack of just making them white?

Answer (score 1):

Although pretty late, let me add my suggestion. Using `multiplot` is not necessary in your case. You can combine different plotting styles in one plot, here: `with lines` and `with boxes`.

Check the example below:

- it creates some random test data. A timestamp every 4 hours and some random y values
- for ytics only on the right side, use `unset ytics` and `set y2tics`.
- there are different ways to average or smooth your data:

1. `smooth bezier` (check `help smooth`)
2. `smooth uniq` if you take the average per day (here: 24 hours from 12:00 to 12:00 the next day)
3. using arrays (available since gnuplot 5.2.0) to calculate an average over `N` datapoints (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56813651/7295599))

**Script:** (works for gnuplot 5.2.0, Sept. 2017)

```
### plot data, average, smooth bezier
reset session
myTimeFmt = "%Y%m%d-%H%M"

# create some random test data
set table $Data1
    t0 = time(0)
    y0 = 21
    plot '+' u (strftime(myTimeFmt,t0+$0*3600*4)):(y0=y0+rand(0)*2-1) w table
set table $Data2
    t0 = time(0)
    plot '+' u (strftime(myTimeFmt,t0+$0*3600*4)):(rand(0)*3+16) w table
unset table

N = 10    # number for averaging
array X[N]; array Y[N]
do for [i=1:N] { X[i]=NaN; Y[i]=NaN}

unset ytics
set y2tics
set key out top center horizontal
set format x "%Y\n%m-%d" timedate
set style fill solid 0.3

myAvgX(colX) = (n=0, X[c%N+1]=timecolumn(colX,myTimeFmt), s=sum[i=1:N] (X[i]==X[i]?(n=n+1,X[i]):0), s/n)
myAvgY(colY) = (n=0, Y[c%N+1]=column(colY), c=c+1, s=sum[i=1:N] (Y[i]==Y[i]?(n=n+1,Y[i]):0), s/n)

plot $Data1 u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w l lc "black" ti "Data1", \
         '' u (timecolumn(1,"%Y%m%d")+12*3600):2 smooth uniq w lp pt 7 lc "red" ti "24h average", \
         '' u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 smooth bezier w l lc "web-green" lw 2 ti "smooth bezier", \
     c=0 '' u (myAvgX(1)):(myAvgY(2)) w l lc "orange" lw 2 ti "average over ".N, \
     $Data2 u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w boxes lc "blue" ti "Data2"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has answered so far, and in the meantime I've managed to solve the first problem, so I'll share it here, in case it could help someone. I hear Stack Overflow encourages us to answer our own questions in cases like this.

To make it work, I used a combination of techniques from:

http://psy.swansea.ac.uk/staff/carter/gnuplot/gnuplot_time_histograms.htm

and studying the gnuplot 5.2 manual, plus a bunch of tips from all over the internet.
This is the resulting graph:

[image: Graph]

And here is the code that produced the graph. It is a bit long, so scrolling may be needed:

```
set output 'graph.png'
set terminal png size 640,396
set origin 0, 0.25             # Origin for graph+margins. (Screen coordinates)
set size 1, 0.75               # X/Y scaling of size of graph+labels+margins
set rmargin at screen 580.0/640   # Distance from border to canvas right edge
set bmargin at screen 120.0/396   # Distance from border to canvas bottom edge

set border front lw 1

# Make left y-axis ticks and numbers disappear (Is there a better way?)
set ytics scale 0
set ytics textcolor rgb "white"

set y2tics               # Put tics and numbers on rightmost y-axis
set y2range [18.5:25.7]  # Range for rightmost y-axis

set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y%m%d-%H%M"
set xtics timedate
set xtics format "%Y-%m-%d"
set xtics rotate
set mxtics 7
# One week is 604800 seconds
set xtics "20180607-1200",604800,"20180617-1200"

# Distance between border and the plotted data. Left, right, top, bottom.
# 1/4 day is 21600 seconds
set offsets 21600, 21600, 0, 0

# For moving average
samples(x) = $0 > 4 ? 5 : ($0+1)
avg5(x) = (shift5(x), (back1+back2+back3+back4+back5)/samples($0))
shift5(x) = (back5=back4, back4=back3, back3=back2, back2=back1, back1=x)

# For initializing the running sum
init(x) = (back1 = back2 = back3 = back4 = back5 = sum = 0)


set multiplot

    # Plot data and running average
    plot sum = init(0), \
    "graph.dat" using 1:2 axes x1y2 title "graph" with linespoints, \
    '' using 1:(avg5($2)) axes x1y2 title "moving average" with linespoints


    # Prepare for the histogram
    unset key      # No key/legend for the histogram
    unset xtics    # Avoid "doubled" labels on the x-axis
    unset y2tics   # Avoid "doubled" labels on the y2-axis
    unset border   # No need to draw the border twice

    # 1/8 day is 10800 seconds
    set boxwidth 10800 absolute
    set style fill solid
    # Distance between border and the plotted data. Left, right, top, bottom.
    # First plot's left/right offsets minus boxwidth is 10800
    set offsets 10800, 10800, 0, 0

    # Plot histogram
    plot "histogram.dat" using 1:2 with boxes lc rgb "#383880" axes x1y2

unset multiplot
```

I'm not quite sure what the idea of the ratios is, in the `rmargin` and `bmargin` commands there. There was some trial and error involved.

If someone could explain this, or has an answer for the "bonus question" in my original post, please feel free.