# Plotting using moving average in Gnuplot to remove noise

Tags: gnuplot, noise, noise-reduction

I want to remove the noise in this plot, using moving average or another solution more focused.

[image: plot example with noise]

My data comes from digital temperature sensors exposed at the same environment, and look like this:

```
00:00:02;24.5;23.00;23.1
00:00:32;24.5;23.00;23.2
00:01:02;24.5;22.00;23.3
00:01:32;24.4;22.00;23.1
00:02:01;24.4;22.00;23.1
00:02:31;24.2;22.00;22.6
00:03:01;24.0;22.00;22.3
00:03:31;23.9;22.00;22.0
00:04:01;23.8;22.00;22.1
00:04:31;23.8;22.00;22.3
00:05:01;23.9;22.00;22.6
00:05:31;24.0;22.00;22.9
00:06:01;24.1;22.00;23.2
00:06:31;24.2;22.00;23.4
00:07:01;24.3;22.00;23.7
00:07:31;24.3;23.00;23.9
00:08:01;24.4;23.00;23.9
00:08:31;24.4;23.00;24.1
00:09:01;24.5;23.00;24.2
00:09:31;24.5;23.00;24.3
```

The entire dataset spans 24 hours, having a entry every 30 seconds, or so, (about 2800+ entries).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56813651/7295599 ?

Comment: @theozh Thanks for your suggestion, I will have a look.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting Average curve for points in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855285/plotting-average-curve-for-points-in-gnuplot)