# Moving Average of csv file data showing initial error in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to use gnuplot to plot the moving average of data (3 columns) in a set of files. The data is from a scanning DVM measurement. The plot is correct after the initial n points of data. But for the initial values the plot is wildly off. The sample code is attached.

```
reset session
set datafile separator ','
set grid x y

set terminal png size 1280,720
set output 'plt.png'

P3_multiplier = 2

#set xrange [0:2000]
n = 5

do for [i=1:n] { eval(sprintf("back_n%d=0", i)) }

shift = "("
do for [i=n:2:-1] {
    shift = sprintf("%sback_n%d = back_n%d, ", shift, i, i-1)
}
shift = shift."back_n1 = x)"

sum = "(back_n1"
do for [i=2:n] {
    sum = sprintf("%s+back_n%d", sum, i)
}
sum = sum.")"

samples(x) = $1 > (n-1) ? n : ($1+1)
avg_n(x)   = (shift_n(x), @sum/samples($1))
shift_n(x) = @shift

FILES = system("ls -1 *.csv")
LABEL = system("ls -1 Res*.csv | sed -e 's/data_//' -e 's/.csv//'")

set multiplot
set lmargin screen 0.3
set yrange [-1:1]
set ylabel "P1" offset 4 textcolor rgb "red"
plot for [i = 1 : words(FILES)] word(FILES,i) using 1:(avg_n($4)) w l title sprintf("P1 %s with %d point avg",word(LABEL,i),n)

set yrange [-1:1]
set ytics offset -8, 0
set ylabel "P2" offset -6 textcolor rgb "green"
replot for [i = 1 : words(FILES)] word(FILES,i) using 1:(avg_n($5)) w l title sprintf("P2 %s with %d point avg",word(LABEL,i),n)

set yrange [-1:1]
set ytics offset -16, 0
set ylabel "P3" offset -14 textcolor rgb "green"
replot for [i = 1 : words(FILES)] word(FILES,i) using 1:((avg_n($3)) * P3_multiplier) w l title sprintf("P3 %s with %d point avg",word(LABEL,i),n)

unset multiplot
```

One of the data files (Res1.csv) is attached here. I have copied to different file names for testing.

```
1,11:51:26:745,0.25,-0.5,0.75
2,11:51:28:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
3,11:51:30:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
4,11:51:32:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
5,11:51:34:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
6,11:51:36:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
7,11:51:38:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
8,11:51:40:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
9,11:51:42:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
10,11:51:44:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
11,11:51:46:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
12,11:51:48:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
13,11:51:50:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
14,11:51:52:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
15,11:51:54:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
16,11:51:56:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
17,11:51:58:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
18,11:52:00:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
19,11:52:02:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
20,11:52:04:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
21,11:52:06:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
22,11:52:08:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
23,11:52:10:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
24,11:52:12:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
25,11:52:14:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
26,11:52:16:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
27,11:52:18:736,0.25,-0.5,0.75
28,11:52:20:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
29,11:52:22:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
30,11:52:24:737,0.25,-0.5,0.75
```

The plot is not as expected during the initial period of the filter (n = 5), but is correct from then on.

[Plot with three parameters and data from two files. Data are overlapping as the files are identical.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vldl3.png)

Am I missing something? I am a newbie and not too familiar with gnuplot. Now running on Ubuntu18, planning to port to Windows8 or Windows10 also.

Thanks in Advance.. :)

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong with your code, but I think it would also make sense that the first moving average is the average over the first `n` values and the last moving average is the average over the last `n` values. That way you get `m-(n-1)` moving averages from `m` values. In short: Don't plot the first `n-1` averages because they are not as smooth as the rest.

Comment: my understanding is that you are looking for: first value `x1/1`, second value `(x1+x2)/2`, third value `(x1+x2+x3)/3`, ...., fifth value `(x1+x2+x3+x4+x5)/5` and sixth value  `(x2+x3+x4+x5+x6)/5`.. and so on.  Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56813651/7295599